# AutoIt: Anyone know what's wrong with this RegRead call?

Tags: registry, autoit

Trying to get the value of this registry key using AutoIt and it keeps failing.

My guess is it's due to the `,` and/or `.` in the key name, but I haven't been able to find any good info on this type of issue in the AutoIt docs or other Google searches. I've tried escaping each one individually and together using the usual escape character `\`, also with no luck.

I've confirmed the key names are correct, and also have tried a completely different reg key without the odd characters in my script just to see if it worked normally, which succeeded.

```
Dim $VMWare_Path = RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\VMware, Inc.\VMware Workstation", "InstallPath")
```

Comment: Well, the commands `ConsoleWrite(RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Apple Computer, Inc.\QuickTime\LocalUserPreferences", "FolderPath") & @CR)` and
`ConsoleWrite(@error & " " & @extended)` work for me as expected, so it must be a problem with your entries, not with the signs. At least there are tons of entries including a "." in the folder **...\Software\Classes** anyways, so the dot can't be the problem. Have you tried replacing "HKLM" with the full string? What is your content of `@error` afterwards?
Do you probably use a AutoIt 64 Bit with a regedit 32?

Comment: What do you get as result when checking  \@error ...
Success: Returns the requested registry value.  \@EXTENDED is set to the type of the value $REG_... . These types are defined in the "Constants.au3" include file. 
Failure: Returns "" and sets the @error flag: 
 1 if unable to open requested key 
 2 if unable to open requested main key 
 3 if unable to remote connect to the registry 
 -1 if unable to open requested value 
 -2 if value type not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
Well, the solution turned out to be that I needed to read from a different registry node depending of the OS version. Final code:

```
Local $VMWPath

if @CPUArch = "X64" Then
   ;x64 Key
   $VMWPath = RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432node\VMware, Inc.\VMware Workstation", "InstallPath")
Else
  ;x86 Key
  $VMWPath = RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\VMware, Inc.\VMware Workstation", "InstallPath")
EndIf
```